# Fetching secret file with Jenkins declarative syntax

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a syntax in a declarative Pipeline to fetch secret file in `environment {}` section ?

I am aware of the following syntax, but I'm not sure it's the recommended way for a declarative Pipeline.

```
  withCredentials( [file(credentialsId: 'my-secret-file', variable: 'MY_SECRET_FILE')])
    {
        sh """
            ln -s ${env.MY_SECRET_FILE} download/mysecretfile.crt
        """
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
environment {
  PATH_TO_SECRET_FILE = credentials('secret-file')  
}
```